# What version of Windows 7 Ultimate do I need?

Tags: windows-7

I completely wiped out my widows xp and removed it from the hard drive. I want to get  windows 7 Ultimate, but the prices are all over the ball park.  So is it the OS program that I need? Will I need something else? Yeah, I'm confused. Any help would be great

Comment: Can you be more specific about what yours unsure about?

Comment: Huh... get Linux or check on forums/search engines. This question is not fitting the SuperUser's FAQ. Please read it.

Answer (score 5):

There are three classes of pricing for Windows. In order of cost:

1. **Upgrade.**  The upgrade options [runs about $173](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DHLV8S).  Even though you removed the Windows XP install, you should still have the license.  That means you should be eligible.  <strike>However, some Windows XP editions are not eligible and you didn't share which edition you had used previously.</strike><sub>I remember reading this, but I can't find a reference so I'm striking it for now.</sub>
2. **OEM.** The OEM version [runs about $175](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116762) and is technically only for distribution with new hardware.  You probably don't qualify.  That said, it will probably install, run and validate just fine.
3. **Retail.** The full retail version [runs about $275](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116718).  You will be eligible for this edition, but of course you must pay an extra $100 to get it.  For that $100 you also get the right to transfer it to a new machine some day, a privilege that is not included with either of the other editions.

If you find prices lower than this, it's probably not a legitimate offer.

<sub><sup>*</sup>All prices current at time of original post, but are likely to have changed since.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is yes you need the OS version because windows 7 is an OS. If your specific about other parts please ask.